# Was a user found from query

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am currently trying to figure out if this is proper for what I"m attempting to do. I am wanting to send the post value username to my model to attempt to see if a user exists in the database with that username. The query should either return an object or an empty array. Is this how the check to see if an actual user was found?

```
$current_user = $this -> user -> get($user_id);
dump_exit($current_user);
if (count($current_user) == 0) {
    $this -> session -> unset_userdata('user_id');
    $this -> session -> sess_destroy();
    redirect('login', 'refresh');
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your description, I would use:

```
if (is_object($current_user))
{
  // user found
}
else
{
  // user not found, unset, etc.
}
```

`count()` is used for arrays and for objects that implement the Countable interface. So without knowing more about the object, checking if it is an actual object seems the best way to go.